# Configuring Python 3 on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Android things

Tags: android, python, adb, raspberry-pi3

I have been following the following tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidthings-assistant/#2

When I get to configuring the virtual python environment I get this:
rpi3:/ # python3
/system/bin/sh: python3: not found

I restarted the adb with adb root, but this doesn't correct the issue. As well using su 0 apt-get update produces that apt-get isn't found. Am I using the command incorrectly here?

Comment: Have you tried installing python3 on your development machine?

Comment: I was attempting to, but I kept running into issues using an su 0 apt-get or install for python. I attempted to follow what was posted 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448844/google-assistant-on-rpi3-with-android-things)
to no avail. One thing it does say is to run it from the /home/pi directory, which didn't exist or I was looking past it. I originally flashed my image using Etcher, but I am going to try and do it through the command tool now to see if that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out perhaps I didn't understand the documentation here. I was getting hung up on the python configuration of the credential.json file. The problem was where I was attempting to do this, which was on the Raspberry Pi running Android things. Which was not needed. Attempting to install python and the virtual environment on the Pi. I ended up creating the credential file on a different machine. My mistake was thinking the development machine meant my Pi, rather than where I am working in Android Studio etc.

Comment: An easy mistake to make.  In general parlance for embedded systems, code you write and compile on a "development machine" runs on a "target".  Go ahead and accept your own answer, so people will see that the question has an accepted answer.  And welcome to StackOverflow.